# New item saving sometimes hangs when there is an attachment

Tags: 2013, list, list-item, attachments

**The list**

We currently have a list which contains items with attached Word documents (one attachment per item) which isn't even 1mb.

**Issue**

The issue someone is having is that when she saves a new item with an attached word document, it will sometimes hangs on the "Working on it..." while still in the add form page.

I tried doing multiple tests on my side without being able to reproduce the issue.

**Logs**

When looking in the logs, I don't find a lot of information appart from this:

> Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005.
>
> Failed to get document content data. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot complete this function     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)

People talking about this error was for field related issues which were constant, which is sadly not the case in this situation.

Has anyone ever faced this kind of issue, and what resolved/helped it?

Comment: i've had this problem and it was because the site isn't in the trusted sites list in the IE options.

Comment: Good point! I know that the site isn't in the user trusted sites, I'll give it a try and see if she ever gets the issue again. Could you please make an answer based on your comment so I can accept it once she confirm me the problem is gone? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem and it was because the site isn't in the trusted sites list in the IE options.

> IE Options -> Security -> Trusted Sites -> Add site to trusted sites.